# Passing a Serial Port Instance

Tags: c#, object-oriented, interfaces

**Background**

I am thinking about designing a (GoF/behavioral) command-pattern interface. I may decide to call this thing `ICommand`. I am thinking that I would have some sort of a queue containing a bunch of command-interface objects.  I would like to exercise the queue, calling the interface method `Execute` for each of the items in this queue as follows...

```
DequeuedItem.Execute(); // invoke the command-pattern
```

For every single item in the queue, until exhausting it.

The implementation for the concrete associated with the `Execute` may look like...

```
// concrete implementation of execute
public void Execute()
{
    mySerialPort.ReadExisting(); // read data from a serial port
}
```

From what I understand, using COM ports can be tricky when it comes to who actually owns the port.

Additionally, there are other reasons why I don't just declare the `SerialPort` inside of the concrete-implementation. Like... lots and lots of commands will need to use that same port (but not at the same time). So I will need to pass the serial port to the concrete implementing `ICommand`. This leads me into my question...

**Question**

Would an *open* serial port still function after I pass it to another object?

Even if it would work, are there other implications I need to be conscious of?

Comment: Passing an object (a class instance) as a parameter to a method (of another object) does not, in and of itself, alter its state, in particular, as in C# we are passing references by value rather than passing objects at all (as, say, C++ does).  So, the port object can be referred to by more than one reference.  You have to manage who is allowed to do what with it, but that's no different for the port object or any other object. (Value type instances, such as int or struct, on the other hand, are copied when passed to methods of other classes (unless they are boxed, or method is on itself).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Passing the reference

Yes it would still work because you are only passing the reference and therefore it doesn't alter the referenced object (nor create a copy)

## Responsibility for opening/closing

There are 3 possible cases:

Only one command uses the serial port. The serial port is completely encapsulated in the command and is opened at the beginning of the command and closed at the end.

At least 2 commands use the serial port and performance isn't a problem (you don't have timings to ensure). Each command has an instance of the serial port (pointing to the same COM port). Each command is responsible for opening/closing. Since the commands are executed sequentially (`DequeuedItem`) there's no conflict on the serial port.

At least 2 commands use the serial port but you can't afford to open/close the serial port for each command. The serial port has to be instancied a level higher and given to every commands that need it. The commands don't decide to open/close the serial port, they assume they receive an already open port and they shouldn't alter its state. The serial port could be opened at the moment a command requiring the serial port is added to the queue. The port could be closed when the queue finishes to execute the last command requiring the serial port.

Within these 3 cases, I think there is no bad solution. Each case is appropriate (or not) depending on the usage you make (sparsly, intensively, accurately, ...). The way you use the serial port seems fine to me.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, and the 1st part makes sense. However, I am making the conscious decision to get data from a serial port inside of the command. Not all commands will even have anything to do with the port, I may have one command that adds 2 + 2... Then I will have a subsequent command that reads a port... I am defining these functionalities in my concretes, and one of them happens to be "reading a port".

Comment: @StevieV I have updated the second part with deeper examples. I hope it better addresses your concern.

Comment: That fourth part is exactly how my system looks, I guess that in terms of the command-pattern... That passed instance would be the "Receiver" right?

Comment: @StevieV That's right. Hope things are clearer for you now. If I think of another implication about serial port's usage, I'll update my post and notify you.

Comment: Great, have you had to use SerialPort before? I would like it if you could update your answer to just explain why or why not you think it's okay to do things this way. As well as provide some of your experience with SerialPort. If you could, thanks.

Comment: @StevieV I've updated my answer a bit (don't know what to say more, lol). I only work with serial ports in Java (the concepts behind stay the same). I have little experience (no industrial experience) with the C# one.